# repeatString in Odin Project

Tags: javascript, function

Please how can I go about the repeated string in odin project? I have done the first test, `repeatString('hey', 3)` but don't know how to go with the other tests, `repeatString('hey', 10)` etc.

```js
 const repeatString = function(str, times) {
    
    let i;
    for(i = 0; i < numberOfTimes - 1; i++) {
        repeatedString += str;
    }

    return repeatedString;
};

let repeatedString = 'hey';
let numberOfTimes = 3;

console.log(repeatString(repeatedString, numberOfTimes));

module.exports = repeatString;
```

Answer (score 0):

To repeat a string in JS, you can simply use the built-in [.repeat() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) on a string.

E.g:

```
let foo = "a";
console.log(foo.repeat(5)); // Logs "aaaaa"
```